# Listing parent directory of FTP home path

Tags: .net, vb.net, url, ftp, uri

I have to list FTP directory `../Catalogue/`.

It was working in .NET 4.0, but not is not working in .NET 4.5.2 anymore.

As I can see, in .NET 4.5.2 that the URI is getting changed. The `../` is removed.

Has anyone any idea, how to keep `../` into my request or alternative solution for the same.

```vb
Dim request As FtpWebRequest =
    DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(
        New Uri("ftp://" + FTPServer + "/%2E%2E/Catalogue/")), FtpWebRequest)
request.Proxy = Nothing
request.UsePassive = True
request.UseBinary = True
request.KeepAlive = False
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("", "")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

Comment: *"As I can see"* - How do you *see* that? Show us! + Can you list the `../Catalogue` directory using a standalone FTP client? Show us its log file.

Comment: While debugging URI property "RequestUri " I can see like 'ftp://" + FTPServer + "/Catalogue/'.

Comment: OK, and the other part of my question?

Comment: Yes I can list directory using stand alone FTP client as well. If I can try from cmd it's working fine. As my code is working with 4.0 but its not working with v4.5.2. Please let me know if you need further information from me.

Comment: If you login with cmd and type `pwd`, what do you get?

Comment: I need to type command to go one back directory "cd ../Catalogue"/ . As FTP structure ls like  by default it will show user's default folder.

Comment: Can you answer my question? - What do you get, if you type `pwd` right after login? Show us a real example.

Comment: Please review http://prnt.sc/ev3m3l cmd operation I am executing to get required files. I need to get catalogue files with Catalogue20170218

Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you answer my question?!?

Answer (score 0):

The `ftp://www.example.com/../Catalogue` is not a valid URL, imo. While it may have worked in the past .NET versions, it's no surprise that it does not anymore.

You should not use `..` in URL. And if, it must be after some actual path, so you have anywhere to go *back* to. Your URL actually looks like you are trying to go above an FTP root. That's not possible.

But from your vague comments, it's clear that you are actually trying to go up from the home path (non-chrooted).

Just use the actual path: `ftp://www.example.com/something/Catalogue`, where the `something` is the path you have masked out in your screenshot.

---

If that `something` is changing for whatever reason, you can use `PrintWorkingDirectory` method to find it out:

```
Dim pwdRequest As FtpWebRequest =
    DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(
        New Uri("ftp://" + FTPServer + "/")), FtpWebRequest)
pwdRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.PrintWorkingDirectory
Dim response As FtpWebResponse = pwdRequest.GetResponse()
Dim path As String = response.StatusDescription
Dim i As Integer = path.IndexOf("""")
If i > 0 Then
    path = path.Substring(i + 1)
    i = path.IndexOf("""")
    If i > 0 Then
        path = path.Substring(0, i)

        Dim request As FtpWebRequest =
            DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(
                New Uri("ftp://" + FTPServer + path + "../")), FtpWebRequest)

        ' Your code here
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. I masked the username using which I logged. And that's dynamic for each user.  Yeah practically its not seems right URL but that trick was working in past version. 
Do you have any idea, is there any alternate for path change in ftp using VB.net 4.5.2?
I appreciate for your helped me.

Comment: You know the username, so you now the path, what's the problem?

Comment: Anyway, see my answer.